# Equivalence of Two Different Irrational Numbers Converse

Tags: number-theory, equivalence-relations

[Equivalence of Two Different Irrational Numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133486/equivalence-of-two-different-irrational-numbers)

I came across this and follow the proof, but I'm wondering how you would prove the converse, that is, if 2 irrational numbers are equivalent then their tail ends of their continued fractions must be equal.